# Appropriate concurrent collection for finding first occurrence

Tags: c#

Suppose we have a collection of fruit objects.

Multiple threads can add/remove from this collection, and types of fruit can appear multiple times:

```
"apple", "pear", "orange", "pear", "apple"
```

Now the system can process different fruit types at the same time, but it will break if 2 threads try and process 2 objects of the same type (2 apples for example).

So when a thread tries to process it's current fruit (i.e. apple), it needs to check that apple is the first apple in the queue. If it's queued up behind another apple, it should wait.

I was planning to use a ConcurrentQueue, but I can't see how I would tell if the apple was the first occurence in queue?

Is there a suitable collection which supports this functionality?

Comment: can you show your code implementation so that we can gain a better understanding of what you are doing or not doing..?

Comment: Is this literally a queue of strings or do the strings here represent the various types of the objects in the queue?

Comment: Also, what does "processing" a fruit mean? What is the task your threads are accomplishing? Please start with a single threaded description of the problem you're solving, *then* you can describe how you want the work distributed among threads (and consequently what characteristics you want in a collection type).

Comment: So is this actually a queue then? It's really not clear what you are doing. Is one thread adding and another removing? What exactly does "process" mean when you say "it will break if 2 threads try and process 2 objects of the same type"

Comment: If one item can't be processed because another "similar" item is being worked on do you want that consumer to stop working until the item it has can be worked on, or do you want it to pick out the next item that is "available for work".

Comment: There might be better ways around this then waiting, if you post more code/where/how it is used we might be able to get more threads working..

Comment: @Servy Have you figured out what the OP means by "when a thread tries to process it's current fruit (i.e. apple), it needs to check that apple is the first apple in the queue."? How does a worker have insight into where in the queue its given task is? Wouldn't that defeat the non random-access nature of a queue?

Comment: @Asad The question is whether or not it's actually vitally important that the items be processed in order, or if he was just using a queue because he had nothing better to use.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep track of the currently processed fruit.

```
HashSet<string> _inProcess = new HashSet<string>();

bool CanProcessFruit(string fruit)
{
    lock(_inProcess)
    {
        if(_inProcess.Contains(fruit))
            return false;
        _inProcess.Add(fruit);
        return true;
    }
 }

 void EndProcessFruit(string fruit)
 {
      lock(_inProcess)
      {
          _inProcess.Remove(fruit);
      }
 }
```

Note that I'm using a HashSet and locking it myself instead of a ConcurrentDictionary. That's because I want `CanProcessFruit` to check the set and add the fruit to the set in one atomic operation. Otherwise, it's a race condition.